# payPal subscription transactions not showing up immediately

Tags: node.js, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

I'm creating recurring payments through payPal subscriptions flow. On the *frontend*, I have a button auto-generated by payPal which redirects me to their domain. After that, it correctly returns the subscriptionID; after that, the frontend calls a backend API which should verify that subscriptionID, to check fields such "status" and so on.
In this *backend* API, I need to store some "paymentID" (one per month, always unique, if the subscription is automatically renewed monthly), which I found to be called "transactionID" on payPal. I use the REST API `GET /v1/billing/subscriptions/{id}/transactions`, which should returns an object with a field `transactions`, which should be an array of transactions. The problem is that sometimes, just after the successful payment, this array is empty. If I wait some time (from few ms to minutes), then every subscription has it's own transactions, in the end.

Is there a way to fix this? Or, alternatively, is there something like transactions on the PayPal environment which can uniquely represents a specific payment?

Answer (score 0):

When a subscription starts it takes time for the first transaction to be created.

Instead of querying the subscriptions API, [create a webhook to be notified of `PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED`events](https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/webhooks/event-names/#subscriptions). This will be useful for the initial transaction as well as all future transactions.

Comment: Thank you @Preston PHX, I thought about it but I have a problem: what if the webhook event arrives before the FE sends the subscription id?